# Rotate camera around object vs rotate object around its center

Tags: performance, three.js

I would like to create an object into the center of a scene (there is nothing else) in three.js and I need controls. I am not want to use Orbit or Trackball controls. 
So the question is which way is more performance: rotate the camera around the object or rotate the object?

Comment: To be clear, are you simply looking to animate the rotation, or do you want the rotation to be interactive?

Comment: Do you mean you want to write your own controls?

Comment: Yes, I am want to write my own interactive controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, and I don't really need to say this, fewer operations yields better performance.

*For your simple example​ case...*

If you have a camera, a light, and a single object, then moving the object will be faster. Even if you parent the light to the camera, there would be more matrix operations to move the camera/light.

*But that's where it ends.*

If you have more objects than you do camera+lights, then it's better to rotate the camera and lights around the object(s). This is the approach used by most controls (including TrackballControls and OrbitControls) because you almost always have more scene objects than cameras+lights.

**Recommendation:** Unless you're never going to use your control for scenes with more than one object, rotate the camera around the objects. Just watch out for [gimbal lock](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock).

Comment: I just start learning three js. Sorry for the inaccuracy.
There are the several objects (around 30 details, some with their own animations and textures) grouped by THREE.Group. And this group is located in the center of the scene.

Comment: My recommendation stands. If you're planning on rotating around a scene, even if you have all the shapes grouped together, moving the camera is easier to do, and more efficient.